# Are there chaotic maps that commute?

Tags: chaos-theory

My question is in the title. You can imagine 1D or 2D maps for example, the simpler the better. Let us say we have chaotic map T and chaotic map R. We need that RT(x(n))=TR(x(n)). (I do not want R= invertible map and $T=R^{-1}$ or $T=R \circ R$).

(Motivation for this question is probably stupid. I imagine series in time and in space (just x direction), which is chaotic in both of this directions. In t - direction operates T and and in x - direction operates R. To have x, t structure one needs commutation of these maps. Though, I hope the question have its relevance in itself.)

Comment: Do you also not want $T = R\circ R$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, I do not want it. (I edited question.)

Comment: Then presumably you want to exclude $R = S^{\circ m}, T = S^{\circ n}$ for any integers $m, n$ and chaotic map $S$.

Comment: You probably also want to also exclude, e.g., $\varphi_t$ a continuous-time chaotic dynamical system (e.g. van der Pol), $R=\varphi_{a}$, $S=\varphi_b$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_+$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: [Crossposted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480714/75633) from Physics SE.